# problem is while loop is not ending in taking input paragraph using system.in in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, inputstream, user-input

I am having problem in taking a hole paragraph as input in java using System.in and storing it in an array. but problem is with while loop is not ending and program stuck in the loop. i have tried many methods but loop is not ending.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList < String > al = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.print("Please Enter Paragraph + \n");
while (!(sc.equals(null))) {
  al.add(sc.next());
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String para = sc.nextLine();
int x = 0;

while (para != null) {

  if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    ParaArray[x] = para;
    para = sc.nextLine();

    x++;
  } else {
    para = null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters in title.

Answer (score 1):

sc is a Scanner object. When you compare sc with null, you will never get true because sc could never be null. Also, your code seems to have a lot of errors. Your question is also unclear. Please provide a proper question...
-Thanks
Tejan Gandhi

Dt: 29th July (After reading your comment):

There are 2 parts of code, one which scans characters and another scans lines.. Because the first "while" loop compares sc (which is a Scanner object) it can never be null and loop can never end.. So instead of doing
sc.equals(null) 
sc.hasNext()

Tell me if that works for you.

Comment: I wanted to take 100 string characters as input using system.in and wanna store it in an array. The problem is while loop is not ending and program remains in tha while loop

Comment: I edited answer. Here's the short summary of what went wrong:
Loop is not ending because the condition in loop is always true. You are comparing: !sc.equals(null) and sc is a "Scanner" object. A scanner object can never be null because you've initialized it. Change the condition in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

when you use "sc.hasNextline",you should put"Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); " before your judgment statement,just like this:

```java
int num = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please input a number");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                num = sc.nextDouble();

            } else {
                System.out.println("It is not a number,please try again！");
                System.out.println("============================");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is for double type inputs but i wanted to take an essay as input using system.in

Answer (score 0):

After your first loop you have already an array of paragraphs so why it is not clear why you need a second loop.
I've also put the scanner in a `try ()` because Scanner is `Closeable` so it is closed at the end.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Please Enter Paragraph + \n");
                String readLine = sc.nextLine();
                if (readLine.length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                al.add(readLine);
            }

            System.out.println("result:"+al);
        }
    }
}
```